# Cisco Phone (7961) won't find voice vlan

Tags: cisco, voip, phone

We have a cisco phone system setup successfully.

I am setting up a bunch of phones, of which, one keeps getting an data vlan ip address from the DHCP server.

Any suggestions?

I have factory reset the phone a number of times.

Comment: Can you verify that the switch port that it's in is configured correctly, or alternately try plugging it in to a known working port?

Comment: Have tried it on ports I can configure other phones on and other various ports with the same result.  It gets an IP from the data vlan :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean the 7961 as I can't find any reference to a Cisco 7661 phone.

Sorry I'm not familiar with the methods used for Cisco's to automatically discover voice VLAN's but a temporary bodge - press settings, **#, then Network configuration, then Operational VLAN ID, and manually enter the desired VLAN.

Also it may be worth doing a factory reset prior to this - pull the power (or network lead if powered via POE), then hold down the # key and power the phone up. Keep holding # until the line buttons blink in sequence, then enter 123456789*0# and the phone should reset to factory settings, then pull needed files. (As you have a Cisco phone system, I'm assuming you have the correct DHCP option for your TFTP server set, as well as the relevant firmware and provisioning files on the TFTP server - if you factory reset without these you will end up with a useless phone).

If after a factory reset it still doesn't behave on known good ports, I would factory reset a known good phone on a known good port just to ensure VLAN wasn't set manually before opening a support case with Cisco.

Comment: Have definitely factory reset a few times without any love... but the **# thing is a godsend! I knew you would be able to manually set things somehow! I'll test this then upvote if works :)

Comment: Oddly enough, even though **# lets me edit some of the settings, Operational VLAN is not one it lets me set manually... blaaaah! Interestingly enough under Security Configuration there is a listing 'Voice VLAN Enabled' and it says no.  ANOTHER uneditable field :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are using as switches, but on catalyst the following configuration should help:

```
interface FastEthernet0/12
 switchport access vlan <data vlan id>
 switchport voice vlan <voice vlan id>
```

Another thing to look at IIRC: the Cisco phones are using [CDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_Discovery_Protocol) to discover the voice vlan and hop into it. While disabling CDP sounds interesting for security reasons, it may break the whole voice lan.

```
Switch#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Switch(config)#cdp run
Switch(config)#interface range fastEthernet 0/1 - 24
Switch(config-if-range)#cdp enable
```

Comment: Amazing advice! But unfortunately this is already configured and my phone system / switch and router setup is working perfectly fine with every other phone... I setup 49 of them before this bugger! Might just be faulty hardware in some way!